# How to upload a file to content folder using standard file uploader?

Tags: apex, lightning-aura-components, lightning

> Cant upload file to content folder from standard file uploader

I have tried several times uploading files to the folder. But every time it shows can't upload file.

If I try to upload file to library it works. For this I am passing library id as record id in lightning file uploader.

Similarly if i am passing folder id as record id it returns error

> 'Cant upload 'filename' '

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot specify ContentFolder Id as `recordId` directly in the `lightning:fileUpload` component but you can handle this as an update in an apex controller method.

Assuming that by default the file will be uploaded to a library, then once file is uploaded invoke an apex method from the event `onuploadfinished` to update folder id to move it to appropriate folder.

`onuploadfinished` is called once you click on done after file upload.

Here is a sample code:

**FileUploader.cmp**

```
<aura:component implements="flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes,force:appHostable,flexipage:availableForRecordHome"
                access="global"
                controller="FileUploader" >
    <aura:attribute name="myRecordId" type="String" 
                        description="Record to which the files should be attached"
                    default="0581t000000HHiAAAW"/> <!-- hardcoded library id for illustration purpose only, adapt as per your use case -->
    <lightning:fileUpload label="Attach doc"
        name="fileUploader"
        multiple="false"
        accept=".pdf, .png"
        recordId="{!v.myRecordId}"
        onuploadfinished="{!c.handleUploadFinished}" />
</aura:component>
```

**FileUploaderController.js**

```
({
    handleUploadFinished: function (cmp, event) {
        // Get the list of uploaded files
        var uploadedFiles = event.getParam("files");
        var documentId = uploadedFiles[0].documentId;//this retrieves the ContentDocumentId
        var fileName = uploadedFiles[0].name;

        var action = cmp.get("c.serverMovetoFolder");
        action.setParams({ docId : documentId });

        // Create a callback that is executed after 
        // the server-side action returns
        action.setCallback(this, function(response) {
            var state = response.getState();
            if (state === "SUCCESS") {
                // do something here on success
                console.log("From server: " + response.getReturnValue());    
            }
            else{
              //handle error here
            }
        });

        $A.enqueueAction(action);
    }
})
```

**FileUploader.cls (apex class)**

`ContentFolderMember` stores the folder association in the field `ParentContentFolderId`, so query the current folder for the document. Then query the folder name you want to move the file into.
Then perform an update on `ContentFolderMember` record to set the new folder id for the file.

```
public with sharing class FileUploader {

    @AuraEnabled
    public static Boolean serverMovetoFolder(String docId) {
        try{
            ContentFolderMember folderMember = [SELECT Id, ParentContentFolderId,ChildRecordId 
                                                from ContentFolderMember where ChildRecordId = :docId limit 1];

            ContentFolder folder = [SELECT Id, name from contentfolder where name ='YourFolderName' limit 1];
            folderMember.ParentContentFolderId = folder.Id;
            update folderMember;
            return true;
        }catch(Exception ex){
            throw new AuraHandledException(ex.getMessage()); 
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. This was the exact thing i was looking for. You saved my time

Comment: @NBR Happy to help :)